# Is it possible to capture all loopback packets on Windows using WFP callouts?

Tags: windows, driver, ndis

I am a developer of **WinPcap**, a famous packet capturing and sending software under Windows. I have ported WinPcap to **NDIS 6 Light-Weight Filter** technique, but it still **doesn't support loopback packets** (such as packets sent to and received from 127.0.0.1) capturing because of Windows' nature: **The loopback packets are handled directly in TCP/IP stack and don't go down to NDIS layer.**

Someone told me that **Windows Filtering Platform** can see the loopback traffic, so I have done some research about it. I have several questions about this.

1) **What are actually loopback packets?** I mean the packets NDIS can't see? Like when I ping 127.0.0.1, these ICMP packets are definitely loopback ones. When I ping an address that a local network adapter has bound to (like 192.168.0.24), it is also loopback I think. **Are these all conditions?** If yes, then I can filter out which packets are loopback ones based on whether their local IPs are 127.0.0.1 or local adapter IPs (like 192.168.0.24).

2) I learnt that WFP has many layers, I think my requirement should use the "**IP Packet (Network Layer)**", I wonder that **can WFP Network Layer captures all loopback packets inbound and outbound**?

3) I don't know **if the loopback packets captured by WFP will have an Ethernet header**? If not, then I think I should manually add Ethernet header to the packet prefix before sending them to user mode, as WinPcap is an ethernet-level packet capture software and many software using WinPcap (like Wireshark) will by default parse the packets from Ethernet layer. However, I think I will let the whole Ethernet header to be all-0, as there's actually no Ethernet header in fact.

Thanks and appreciated for your help!